# How many different 5 letters word can be possible by using the letters from "Cambridge" with all the vowels in it?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

So I took the vowels (a,e,i) permute them 3p3 and then I choose 6c2.Here I get baffled and can't figure out what should I do next.

By the way multiply 3p3 and 6c2 comes up with 180 which is not the answer.The answer is 1800.

Please explain where I made the mistake.Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first choose the 5 letters in the word, *then* permute it.

You must choose all 3 vowels, and 2 consonants from the 6; there are $6C2 = 15$ choices.

Then you permute the 5 chosen letters; there are $5P5 = 5!$ choices.

Multiplying, we have $6C2 \times 5! = 15 \times 120 = 1800$ different words.

Comment: Can you please explain Why I have to multiply 5P5 ?

Comment: You have 5 letters, now you need to permute/rearrange them.

Comment: I choose 5 letters then permute them.And I have to do that for 15 times in a row.I don't know but somehow that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose $2$ out of the $6$ letters. That is ${6 \choose 2}$ ways as you said.

Now you have $5$ letters and so just permute them. So your answer is ${6 \choose 2} \times 5!$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Take 3 vowels (1 way) & take 2 consonants out of 6 consonants => 6C2 = 1 * 15 = 15 ways to select required 5 letters.

Secondly, the number of ways to arrange those 5 letters is 5*4*3*2*1 = 120

The answer is 120 * 15 = 1800